# How Can I use this Library in my Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, licensing

I have found a [Library](https://github.com/appsome/AccordionView). But Want to conform that Can  I use it freely in my App. My Requirement is same like this Library. So I want to create a accordion view with two header.

I want to conform their License policy as given in their file :

```
/*
    AccordionView.h

    Created by Wojtek Siudzinski on 19.12.2011.
    Copyright (c) 2011 Appsome. All rights reserved.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
*/
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you have to conform to license requirements:

> It allows you to:
>
> > freely download and use Apache software, in whole or in part, for personal, company internal, or commercial purposes;
> >
> > use Apache software in packages or distributions that you create.
>
> It forbids you to:
>
> > redistribute any piece of Apache-originated software without proper attribution;
> >
> > use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that the Foundation endorses your distribution;
> >
> > use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that you created the Apache software in question.
>
> It requires you to:
>
> > include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software;
> >
> > provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software.
>
> It does not require you to:
>
> > include the source of the Apache software itself, or of any modifications you may have made to it, in any redistribution you may assemble that includes it;
> >
> > submit changes that you make to the software back to the Apache Software Foundation (though such feedback is encouraged).

See https://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html

Comment: Thanks for reply , How to do this "include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software"

Comment: Thanks , Can you give me a link to download this license file.